# Complex differentiability equivalent to linear approximation

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $G \subset \mathbb C$ be an open set and $f: G \to \mathbb C$ a complex function on $G$. Prove that the function $f$ is complex differentiable at a point $z \in G$ if and only if there exists a constant $A \in \mathbb C$ such that 
>   \begin{align*} f(z+h) -f(z) =
> Ah+\omega(h) \end{align*} 
>   where $\omega : G_z \to \mathbb C$ satisfies
>   \begin{align*} \lim_{|h| \to 0} |\omega(h)|/|h| = 0, \qquad h \ne 0,
> \, z+h \in G, 
> \end{align*} 
>   where $G_z = \{h \in \mathbb C: h+z \in G\}$.

*Proof:* 
"$\Rightarrow$": Let $f$ be complex differentiable at $z$. Then the limit
\begin{align*}
f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h}
\end{align*}
exists and is finite. Set $A := f'(z)$ and 
\begin{align*}
\omega(h) := f(z+h) - f(z)
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{|\omega(h)|}{|h|} = \lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{|f(z+h) - f(z)|}{|h|} = 0 ???
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
Ah + \omega(h) &= f'(z)h + f(z+h) - f(z) \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} h + f(z+h) - f(z) \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} f(z+h)-f(z)  + f(z+h) - f(z) \\
&= f(z)-f(z) + f(z+h)-f(z) 
= f(z+h)-f(z).
\end{align*}

Question: I have still some troubles with $\omega$ as I don't see that it satisfies the condition.

"$\Leftarrow$": Suppose there exists $A$ with the stated properties. Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}= \frac{Ah+\omega(h)}{h} = A + \omega(h)/h \xrightarrow{h \to 0} A,
\end{align*}
and so $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: In the forward implication you didn't define $\omega$ which you used in your definition of $A$.  Also you define A in a way that depends on $h$. $A$ is supposed to be a constant (not depending on $h$).

Comment: How do I need to define $\omega$ then?

Comment: Set $A=f'(z)$ (this makes sense since you are given $f'(z)$ by hypothesis, unlike $\omega$) and make $\omega (h)$ whatever it needs to be to satisfy your first equation (a certain difference).

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of the proof, the definition of $\omega$ should be changed to
$$\begin{align*}
\omega(h) := f(z+h) - f(z) - A h
\end{align*}$$
With this definition,
$$ 
\lim_{ |h|  \to 0} \frac{ \omega(h) }{ h } = \lim_{|h| \to 0} \left(\frac{ f(z+h) - f(z) }{ h } -A\right) =   A-A=0
 $$
hence
$$ \lim_{ |h|  \to 0} \frac{ |\omega(h)| }{ |h |}=0$$
(A function tends to zero if and only if its absolute value does.)